# How do I modify the HTTP response code and message in java

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

My goal is to modify the http response status code and the content that comes with it (not using spring by the way). The current response I'm getting is an HTTP 501 and I would like to modify that response to return an HTTP 200 instead with a custom message.

I've tried using `javax.servlet.Filter` and found out that that won't work (as far as I know) since I can't modify the response after the `filterChain.doFilter()` call. I tried redirecting a response using `httpResponse.sendError()` but didn't work since I'm getting an `IllegalStateException` telling me about the reponse was already committed or something like that.

I've also tried adding an `<error-page>...</error-page>` block in my web.xml using a web servlet as the `location` but apparently that does not work for unsupported methods and invalid headers (tried using a random string as request method; also tried `Transfer-Encoding: random` as an invalid header); works for invalid uri paths though.

Is there a way to create a general "filter" mechanism where I can modify the response code and message when there's a HTTP error code response?

Comment: Is this pure servlets and filters or something like JAX-RS?

Comment: @stdunbar pure servlets and filters